# Magento 2.4.1-p1 CE?: "main.ERROR: Can not resolve reCAPTCHA parameter..."

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.1

In /var/log/exception.log, I've been getting the following ERROR for over a week and can't figure out how to fix it:

```
main.ERROR: Can not resolve reCAPTCHA parameter. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\InputException(code: 0): Can not resolve reCAPTCHA parameter. at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-ui/Model/CaptchaResponseResolver.php:25)"} []
```

reCAPTCHA *seems* to be working, despite the error msg.

[edited to add]: I'm using reCAPTCHA v3 Invisible on Storefront, so I suppose I wouldn't know if it was allowing everyone through - not sure how to test that it is rejecting when it should.

I've tried re-setting the file and directory permissions, clearing and flushing cache, re-indexing.  None of these things have resolved it.

BTW, I switched my store from production mode to developer mode, but receiving the reCAPTCHA ERROR in the exception.log regardless of mode.

Please tell me how to fix this?
Thanks,
Evelyn

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Webninja no, I haven't. I have since upgraded to Magento 2.4.2-p1, but still have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also currently facing the same issue on magento 2.4 with the type type_invisible. My keys are 100% correct. Found this and it looks like it might be related to magento itself and the fact that it might just be a validation message issue due to magento himself not handling keys properly ? Don't really know what to think about it.

See : [Magento community](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Can-not-resolve-reCAPTCHA-parameter/td-p/463197)

If someone got more intell about the real cause behind all that, might be awesome. On my case i'm using

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from your google API keys. Make sure these keys are correct

Comment: My google API keys are correct, they haven't changed and as I said reCAPTCHA seems to be working.

Comment: Just to follow up: I re-entered my google API keys, because why not.  About 3 hrs later, the same error appeared again in exception.log and debug.log.  So it's not an issue with the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem on the Magento 2.4.2. both API keys are correct and ReCaptcha works on the contact page, login page, create account page but only Braintree credit form Recaptcha not working. It displays ReCaptcha but not doing validation.

Hope anyone has a solution please share

Comment: How did you find out what page the error originate from? We have the same error messages in 2.4.2 but doesn't know what page they are triggered on.

Comment: We don't see any error in the frontend and no error in the log file. ReCaptcha passes without validation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the internet speed is very slow. The customer submitted the form before the Recaptcha component was generated. That causes the Recaptcha to not be validated in FE, but will cause an error in BE.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly SPAM bots. Check the timestamp in the access log against the timestamp in the exception log. Check the IP address and you can usually see that it's just a SPAM bot trying to register accounts or submit to newsletter forms.

Comment: Have got any fix for spam register account?